# [snowflake python connector ]How to bindings inside a string format

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use data binding when executing sql.
I just want to binding in the middle of the string, but it doesn't work.

I tried the following, but all of them resulted in execution errors.

Python

```py
param = {
    "env": "dev"
    "s3_credential": "secret"
}
cursor().execute(sql, param)
```

sql1

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE my_s3_stage_demo
    URL='s3://my-stage-demo-'%(env)s'/tmp/'
    credentials = (aws_role = %(s3_credential)s )
    FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE=JSON);
```

error message1

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 091006 (22000): Bucket name 'my-stage-demo-'dev'' in the stage location is not supported. Valid bucket names must consist of lowercase letters, digits, hyphens '-', and periods '.'.
```

SQL2

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE my_s3_stage_demo
    URL='s3://my-stage-demo-%(env)s/tmp/'
    credentials = (aws_role = %(s3_credential)s )
    FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE=JSON);
```

error message2

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 32 unexpected ''/tmp/''.
```

I want to execute the binding result as follows, but how should I specify it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE my_s3_stage_demo
    URL='s3://my-stage-demo-dev/tmp/'
    credentials = (aws_role = "secret" )
    FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE=JSON);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind substrings, only complete syntactical elements.

In Python, you can do something like:

```
cursor.execute(
  "SELECT t.*, 'P'||:2 p2 FROM IDENTIFIER(:1) t",
  [['"my_db"."my_schema"."my_table"', '2. parameter']]
)
```

You can only use parts of a value where expressions are allowed (like `'P'||:2` above).  There is also some provision for identifiers like the table name above using `IDENTIFIER()`.

Unfortunately, for the `CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE` command there seems to be no support for using expressions for eg an s3 bucket, or bind variables at all.
Which means you have to use replacement for the SQL text, not variable binding.